# Linux Kernel - Inner Crypto API

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography, kernel

Since I will use the Linux's built-in crypto API for different purposes, I've been reading the sources carefully.
While attempting to understand what's going on, I have been struck by the *instance handling* part of the code.

The code is C, nevertheless this part is clearly object-oriented. Thus, when a *user* needs to perform some encryption, it will ask for the allocation of a *transform* instance which will involve the use of a particular algorithm in a particular encryption mode. The pair (*algorithm*, *mode*) will be handled this way in the crypto API :

1. The "pure" algorithm is stored in a `struct crypto_alg` structure.
2. The mode is defined through a `struct crypto_template` which says how to initialize a specific `struct crypto_instance`

Here are the definitions of the structures `crypto_instance` and `crypto_spawn`

```c
struct crypto_instance {
    struct crypto_alg alg;
    /*
     * The alg struct will be filled according to the template 'alloc' method
     */
    struct crypto_template *tmpl;
    struct hlist_node list;

    void *__ctx[] CRYPTO_MINALIGN_ATTR;
};

struct crypto_spawn {
    struct list_head list; // Embedded list_head to list the spawns
    struct crypto_alg *alg; // Ptr to the underlying algorithm
    struct crypto_instance *inst;
    const struct crypto_type *frontend;
    u32 mask;
}
```

Then, to me it looks like there is a kind of hierarchy : the `crypto_spawn` is here to manage the combination of an encryption mode defined by a `crypto_instance` and a *pure* encryption algorithm defined by a `crypto_alg`. In terms of model object, we can see that `crypto_instance` inherits `crypto_alg` and it is totally reasonable to consider "cascading" templates over a given algorithm.

The thing I don't understand is why the `crypto_spawn` and the `crypto_instance` structures are not merged together. This question has even more struck me when I met the instance allocation code :

```c
struct crypto_instance *crypto_alloc_instance(const char *name,
                                struct crypto_alg *alg)
{
    struct crypto_instance *inst;
    struct crypto_spawn *spawn;
    int err;

    inst = crypto_alloc_instance2(name, alg, 0);
    if (IS_ERR(inst))
        goto out;

    spawn = crypto_instance_ctx(inst);
    /*
     * This line expands to :
     * spawn = inst->__ctx;
     */
    err = crypto_init_spawn(spawn, alg, inst,
                CRYPTO_ALG_TYPE_MASK | CRYPTO_ALG_ASYNC);

    if (err)
        goto err_free_inst;

    return inst;

err_free_inst:
    kfree(inst);
    inst = ERR_PTR(err);

out:
    return inst;
}
```

The `crypto_alloc_instance2` just allocates the physical memory to hold the structure and fills the `inst->alg` structure's name fields :

```c
void *crypto_alloc_instance2(const char *name, struct crypto_alg *alg,
                        unsigned int head)
{
    struct crypto_instance *inst;
    char *p;
    int err;

    p = kzalloc(head + sizeof(*inst) + sizeof(struct crypto_spawn),
                GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!p)
        return ERR_PTR(-ENOMEM);

    inst = (void *)(p + head);
    /* Names editing + error checking ... */
    return p;
}
```

As you can see, a spawn is "physically" bound to an instance, so why are they defined separately. I find it very troubling when then trying to understand how the whole thing is mixed and handled.

At the moment, the only reason that came to my mind is that it allows the API to **opacify** the underlying algorithm from the `crypto_instance` object. But since the last bytes of the structure will easily give the spawn through the `spawn = inst->__ctx` instruction, it is not very very opaque.

As a recall after this bunch of code and comments, the question is :
*What reasons lead the developers to make this "separation" between the instance and the spawn structure ?*

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment !

**Note** : I added the tag cryptography because I thought that developers interested in this tag have probably already taken a look into the Linux Kernel crypto part.